# Shell script: command to print a sentence

Tags: shell

I can't find a command to print a sentence in a shell script.
For example on google

```
firefox http://www.google.com    
[[command that writes "hello world" on the searchbar]]
```

the result should be https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=hello+world&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=2&gws_rd=ssl

It should be easy but I can't find it

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

According to firefox manual, you can add this option:

```
-search term
     Search for term with your default search engine.
```

If your default search engine is google, this command will work:

```
firefox -search "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the `q` query parameter directly to `search` in the `URL`:

```
firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world"
```

Comment: The question description is not a mere rewording but a completely different problem specification from the previous. It is advised to create a new question in these situations otherwise any existing answers or comments would be obsolete and wrongfully downvoted as irrelevant.